# Box API access token: invalid_client

Tags: oauth-2.0, box

I am trying to work with the Box API and need an access token. I followed the tutorial video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ha26tN8amI0 to get an authorization code and then exchange it for an access and refresh token. Here is the post request I made into Post Man:

```
https://api.box.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=<my_client_id>&client_secret=<my_client_secret>&code=<code_given_on_redirect>&redirect_uri=http://0.0.0.0
```

The response I get is:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "The client credentials are invalid"
}
```

- Unless I am completely losing my mind, I am positive I am entering the correct client_id and client_secret from my application page. (I tried several times.)
- I sent this post request in less than 30 seconds after it was generated.

Any idea what I might be missing? Thanks.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and opened a github issue on their ruby repo: https://github.com/cburnette/boxr/issues/22